# How to sort by a specific key and then get the first result in the sorted collection into a group in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-to-entities, sql-order-by

I've got a database where I need to get latest message with (which means a message to OR from me) each user. I'm using LINQ-to-Entities and here is my query:

```
var latestMessageFromEachUser = from m in Database.Messages.Include(m => m.From).Include(m => m.To)
  where !m.IsDeleted && (m.ToID == User.ID || m.FromID == User.ID)
  orderby m.ID descending
  let otherEnd = m.ToID == userId ? m.FromID : m.ToID
  group m by otherEnd into g
  orderby g.FirstOrDefault().ID descending
  select g.FirstOrDefault();
```

I think variable names are self explanatory. I'm ordering descending by ID as it's the identity column and is auto-incremented, so it's effectively ordering by date. However, when I execute this query, I'm getting the *oldest* message with each user instead of *newest*.

Why?

Comment: `ID` in the groupby field is userId not the messageId, I guess that's why you see messages are not sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe something like the following:

```
  var test = from m in Database.Messages
             where !m.IsDeleted && (m.ToID == User.ID || m .FromID == User.ID)
             orderby m.ID descending
             let otherEnd = m.ToID == userId ? m.FromID : m.ToID
             group m by otherEnd into g
             select new { g.Key, g.OrderByDescending(n => n.ID).FirstOrDefault() };
```

The main issue I see is the sorting on g.FirstOrDefault().ID which got the first of your grouped messages by user and then tried sorting on it which in effect would do nothing

Comment: Yes it worked. I didn't realize I was ordering incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below

```
    var latestMessageFromEachUser = from m in Database.Messages.Include(m => m.From).Include(m => m.To)
  where !m.IsDeleted && (m.ToID == User.ID || m.FromID == User.ID)  
  let otherEnd = m.ToID == userId ? m.FromID : m.ToID
  group m by otherEnd into g
   orderby m.ID descending
  select g.FirstOrDefault();
```